# virtual ICollection lazy load in Entity Framework with Model Builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have little problem with the EF and I'm not sure how to explain it, so I just give an example:

Here's my Objects:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    // Need model builder example for this one
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to lazy load / map the virtual ICollection 'User.Events' through 'Event.Tag.User' without any database table changes?

7.3.2014

Here's an example SLQ clause, where user with UserId 1:

```
SELECT Events.EventId
FROM Events
INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagId = Events.TagId
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId = Tags.UserId
WHERE Users.UserId = 1
```

I'm not sure but I'm looking maybe something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(user => user.Events).WithMany(...
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access it now? Can you give an example of how you're doing this?

Comment: Well when adding this to User class:

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

EF Adds 'User_UserId' field to the 'Events' Table and then it's modifying the database table. :-/

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, you want to add the Events property to User but without changing the Events table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as your context is not disposed, any virtual property you access will make another trip to the database. If you are having a specific problem, maybe it would help to post the error message. I see nothing wrong with your code right now.

Comment: The code is OK, but "EF Adds 'User_UserId' field to the 'Events' Table and then it's modifying the database table."